# Hibernate 4 with Java 8 and Maven 3: Turn off/redirect logging (for beginners)

Tags: hibernate, maven, logging

I am trying to ramp up on Hibernate 4 with no experience in any prior version of Hibernate (or another ORM, for that matter).  This has been very frustrating. I have yet to find a tutorial or book that explicitly lists and explains every step needed to the tutorial project working.  It does not help that I am new to Maven as well.

I have managed through trying bits and pieces of various tutorials to get a very simple project working.  So far, all I am trying to do is print out the objects loaded from a table in which the POJO is bound to the table using annotations.

My code works, but the console is cluttered by a massive slew of log messages.  I would like to either turn this log off (at least until I need to debug a problem) or redirect this output to a file.

Currently, I have tried several approaches to turn off logging I have found on StackOverflow and other sites.  Nothing works (and one of the "fixes" results in a Maven error).  POM, programmatic, and Log4j.properties fixes have made no dent in the size of the log.

Here is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sadakatsu</groupId>
    <artifactId>all</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>all</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- <version>2.3</version> -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.5.4.v20111024</version>
                                    <destFileName>jetty-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>

        <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost/tickettoride
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
            root
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
            <!-- redacted -->
        </property>

        <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
        <mapping class="com.sadakatsu.tickettoride.orm.City" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is my `log4j.properties` file:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

Here is the core of my code:

```
package com.sadakatsu.main;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

import com.sadakatsu.tickettoride.orm.City;

public class HibernateDemo {
    private SessionFactory factory;
    private ServiceRegistry registry;

    private HibernateDemo() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        registry = (
            new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                configuration.getProperties()
            ).buildServiceRegistry()
        );
        factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(registry);
    }

    public SessionFactory getFactory() {
        return factory;
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        factory.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HibernateDemo hd = new HibernateDemo();

        Session session = hd.getFactory().openSession();

        Query q = session.createQuery("from City");

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<City> cities = (List<City>) q.list();

        System.out.println("Cities:");
        for (City city : cities) {
            System.out.format("  - %s\n", city);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my expected output:

```
Cities:
  - Atlanta
  - Boston
  - Calgary
  - Charleston
  - Chicago
  - Dallas
  - Denver
  - Duluth
  - El Paso
  - Helena
  - Houston
  - Kansas City
  - Las Vegas
  - Little Rock
  - Los Angeles
  - Miami
  - Montréal
  - Nashville
  - New Orleans
  - New York
  - Oklahoma City
  - Omaha
  - Phoenix
  - Pittsburgh
  - Portland
  - Raleigh
  - Saint Louis
  - Salt Lake City
  - San Francisco
  - Santa Fe
  - Sault St. Marie
  - Seattle
  - Toronto
  - Vancouver
  - Washington
  - Winnipeg
```

And here is what I get:

```
22:52:26.254 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider
22:52:26.270 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@ba4d54
22:52:26.270 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@ba4d54
22:52:26.270 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.lang.Boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@ba4d54
22:52:26.270 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration numeric_boolean -> org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType@6f79caec
22:52:26.270 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration true_false -> org.hibernate.type.TrueFalseType@5c0369c4
22:52:26.270 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration yes_no -> org.hibernate.type.YesNoType@17ed40e0
22:52:26.270 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration byte -> org.hibernate.type.ByteType@3930015a
22:52:26.270 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration byte -> org.hibernate.type.ByteType@3930015a
22:52:26.270 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.lang.Byte -> org.hibernate.type.ByteType@3930015a
22:52:26.270 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration character -> org.hibernate.type.CharacterType@224aed64
22:52:26.270 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration char -> org.hibernate.type.CharacterType@224aed64
22:52:26.270 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.lang.Character -> org.hibernate.type.CharacterType@224aed64
22:52:26.270 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration short -> org.hibernate.type.ShortType@75412c2f
22:52:26.270 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration short -> org.hibernate.type.ShortType@75412c2f
22:52:26.270 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.lang.Short -> org.hibernate.type.ShortType@75412c2f
22:52:26.270 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration integer -> org.hibernate.type.IntegerType@483bf400
22:52:26.270 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration int -> org.hibernate.type.IntegerType@483bf400
22:52:26.270 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.lang.Integer -> org.hibernate.type.IntegerType@483bf400
22:52:26.285 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration long -> org.hibernate.type.LongType@2cfb4a64
<!-- several hundred more lines deleted for space -->
Cities:
  - Atlanta
  - Boston
  - Calgary
  - Charleston
  - Chicago
  - Dallas
  - Denver
  - Duluth
  - El Paso
  - Helena
  - Houston
  - Kansas City
  - Las Vegas
  - Little Rock
  - Los Angeles
  - Miami
  - Montréal
  - Nashville
  - New Orleans
  - New York
  - Oklahoma City
  - Omaha
  - Phoenix
  - Pittsburgh
  - Portland
  - Raleigh
  - Saint Louis
  - Salt Lake City
  - San Francisco
  - Santa Fe
  - Sault St. Marie
  - Seattle
  - Toronto
  - Vancouver
  - Washington
  - Winnipeg
```

Can someone explain to this absolute beginner how I can either turn off the logging altogether or redirect the output to a file?  Either approach will get me moving forward.

If necessary, a clean version of my whole project can be found at [whole project in question](http://sadakatsu.com/all.7z).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open the file called `log4j.properties` in the folder `src/main/resources` in a text editor.
2. To this file add `log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ERROR` and save the file.

This will switch off all debug logs printed out by Hibernate classes.  If at any point you need detailed information about Hibernate, change the line to `log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG`.

Otherwise, post more information, such as your `log4j.properties`.

**Edit**: Based on the source code you have posted, I can see that your application is using [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) as the primary logging framework.  Logback is being imported as a result of the dependency on `spring-boot-starter-web`.  Logback is a successor to the original Log4J framework and an implementation of the SLF4J API that provides a bridge to route all log messages from the Log4J API to the SLF4J API.  This is why your Log4J configuration is simply being ignored.

You need to create a file called `logback.xml` under `src/main/resources` and add the following content to it:

```
<configuration>
  <logger name="org.hibernate" level="ERROR"/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is one of the solutions I have tried, since it is frequently recommended.  It does not work.  I will add my `log4j.properties` file (which includes only this line) to my question.

Comment: You will have to post a sample application somewhere in that case.  Something else may be overriding your log4j configuration.  Only you can find that out because others don't have access to your code.

Comment: I have cleaned my project and posted a link to it in my question.  I have removed my database password from `hibernate.cfg.xml` and have added a SQL script so you can create a copy of my database.  It can be found at `all\src\main\resources\tickettoride.sql`.

Comment: Due to the dependency on Spring Starter Web, the application is using Logback as the logging framework instead of Log4J, thereby ignoring the Log4J configuration.  I have edited my answer to help you configure Logback.